# Not able to debug my html codes in Visual Studio Code and not able to link my CSS page to my HTML page

Tags: html, css, debugging, linker

I created some stylesheets to make styling easier for me but it wouldn't link to my html pages. I've entered the  command
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`
Where style.css is the name of the file.
And this is an image of the CSS file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BeKt.jpg).
I've checked the indentation to make sure they correspond but I didn't find anything wrong.
[This is an image of the HTML file I'm trying to link with the CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3qKA.jpg)
Secondly, my files suddenly won't debug. I'm using chrome as my default debugger. I've tried to fix it by trying to change somethings in launch.json but it's not working out.
The browser says 'this site can't be reached.
Localhost refused to connect.
[This is an image of the report written on the browser when debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI1Lu.jpg)
While trying to fix the problem, I've changed some things in the launch.json and I don't remember it's default content. But it's like this now:
[This is an image of how my launch.json looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msPLX.jpg)
So, that's it. Pls, help me and fix these problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any webserver on your captures. Make sure you have

1. modified the hosts on your system
2. Have an active webserver if you want to use url like http://localhost:8080, like wamp or docker image

Otherwise you can just open the html file with your navigator by drag&droping it in your navigator. Should work fine if your relative path file are correct.

Good day !

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but I don't really understand most of the terms you used coz' I'm a newbie in this tech stuff. Pls, is it possible for you to break the answers down for me and show me how to do it? I'd do my own research on the big terms I don't understand, but pls, help me, if you can. Thank you.